# prove n divides $[\mathbb{F}[\alpha]:\mathbb{Q}]$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

$\mathbb{Q}<\mathbb{F}<\mathbb{C}$ - field extensions, such that $[\mathbb{F}:\mathbb{Q}]=m \in \mathbb{N}$

p is a prime number, $\alpha=p^{\frac{1}{n}}$

gcd(m,n)=1

### prove n divides $[\mathbb{F}[\alpha]:\mathbb{Q}]$

**My thoughts:**

$\mathbb{F}<\mathbb{R}$ since otherwise $m=[\mathbb{F}:\mathbb{Q}]\ge [\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{Q}] = \infty$, which is a contradiction.

moreover if $[\mathbb{F}[\alpha]:\mathbb{Q}]$ is finite then $[\mathbb{F}[\alpha]:\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{F}[\alpha]:\mathbb{F}]*[\mathbb{F}:\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{F}[\alpha]:\mathbb{F}]*m$

$\{ 1,\alpha,\alpha^2,... \}$ is clearly linearly dependent over $\mathbb{F}$ since $\alpha^k$ (for $k\ge n$) is a multiplication of $\alpha^{k-n}$ by a rational constant.

if $B=\{ 1,\alpha,\alpha^2,..., \alpha^{n-1} \}$ is independent its span (with coefficients from $\mathbb{F}$) is $\mathbb{F}[\alpha]$ and therefore $[\mathbb{F}[\alpha]:\mathbb{F}] = n$

Is it about right? and how can I tell the set B is linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}$?

thanks

Comment: The first line under "my thoughts" is wrong. You seem to believe that either $\;\Bbb F\le \Bbb R\;$ **or** $\;\Bbb R\le \Bbb F\;$, but it can be that neither is true, for example $\;\Bbb F=\Bbb Q(i)\;$ . Besides this, it seems to be that $\;\alpha\in\Bbb C\;$ ...

Comment: You are right. indeed, this is a mistake. omitting this line from the paragraph, can you help me get closer to the proof? I can't figure this one out =]

Comment: Don’t you have a chain $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q(\alpha)\subset\Bbb F(\alpha)$? What is $[\Bbb Q(\alpha) : \Bbb Q]$?